# LVP instillation over removed Ceramic Tile/Ditra

Tags: subfloor, vinyl-flooring, renovation

We have an elevated beach home with OSB subfloor. I’m trying to save money on the overall renovation project.  I am doing the demo myself but have a flooring company scheduled to install LVP.

There was Ceramic tile layer over DITRA.  I have removed most of it with a hammer drill. There are some small pieces of the DITRA that are adhered to the subfloor but not very tall or wide.

How smooth do I have to make the floor for LVP instillation? Any suggestions other than a grinder?

Comment: Most hard surface type flooring wants a flat surface close to a pool/snooker table, but does not need to be level.  If you can feel the difference with socks on your feet, probably too much.

Comment: sorry but grinder is your best option

Comment: What do the instructions on the flooring say? If the company is providing it so you don't have instructions to read, what do _they_ say?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the thickness and quality of the new LVP. A rule of thumb is anything thicker than a dime will be felt under the flooring.